# How to fix the following error . TypeError: __init__() got an uexpected keyword argument 'n_iter'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture

gmm = GaussianMixture(
    n_components = 8, 
    n_iter = 200, 
    covariance_type='diag',
    n_init = 3
)
```

Comment: By using the correct argument name, `n_init`, rather than `n_iter`, I guess. It's in [the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.html)

Comment: Can you post GaussianMixture class definition, please?

Comment: Actually, you may have wanted `max_iter`. It's not clear. But `n_iter` is not an argument that the object takes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give `max_iter` for number of EM iterations, instead of `n_iter`. `n_iter` is not valid parameter for GussianMixture model.

[Doumentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.html)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture

gmm = GaussianMixture(
    n_components = 8, 
    max_iter = 200, 
    covariance_type='diag',
    n_init = 3
)
```